# Any good website which teaches algorithms in preparation for job interviews?

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for any good websites which teach algorithms in preparation for job interviews?

Comment: what kind of job? software product manager, programmer, ...

Comment: Let me guess - is this for a Google interview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming Interviews Exposed is a good crash course, it will have a lot of the general questions that you *must* know.  It's a good start, especially if you have little time.  This probably won't get you all the way there, though, for a tough interview. To really do well, you need to have a good understanding of the fundamental algorithms. The Algorithm Design manual is a good mix between practice and theory, and is a bit quicker/more accessible than the classic Intro to Algorithms

Links to the books:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Interviews-Exposed-Secrets-Landing/dp/0471383562](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471383562)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena/dp/1849967202/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1305239723&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202)
- http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_33?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=cormen+introduction+to+algorithms&sprefix=cormen+introduction+to+algorithms

I pretty strongly disagree with using TAOCP. If you're looking for a well-written , rigorous and comprehensive resource, this is the book, but for this, I think it's something that would only yield benefits after a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

If time is too short to read a book, check out [Get that job at Google](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html). Then search for its recommended learnings on [wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Wikipedia is great for describing algorithms in understandable language. With a little bit of filtering, stackoverflow can be a nice complement for understanding more practical applications for the algorithms. It seems a lot of algorithms students come here to do their homework.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get Donald Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming" book series from a library/store, that'll be the end of your quest.

> American Scientist has included this work among "100 or so Books that shaped a Century of Science", referring to the 20th century, and within the computer science community it is regarded as the first and still the best comprehensive treatment of its subject. Covers of the third edition of Volume 1 quote Bill Gates as saying, "If you think you're a really good programmer . . . read (Knuth's) Art of Computer Programming . . . You should definitely send me a résumé if you can read the whole thing." The New York Times referred to it as "the profession's defining treatise".

Find out more about this wonderful book series at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

Comment: +1 for the greatest 4 books ever. (wait I kinda liked a few by Umberto Eco too; hmm)

Comment: Yep, let's wish Knuth to stay healthy and be able to complete all books as planned.

Comment: TAOCP is great but it's not necessarily suitable for this purpose.